# Initializing base class const member in most derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance

In the below code, I initialize `const` member of `Base` class in the most derived class `Grandchild`.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int x_) : x(x_) {}

private:
    const int x;
};

class Child : public virtual Base {
public:
    virtual ~Child() = 0;
};

class Grandchild : public virtual Child {
public:
    Grandchild() : Base(42) {}
};

Child::~Child() {}

int main() {
    Grandchild gc;
}
```

In case of virtual inheritance, the `Base` class constructor is called by the most derived class. Hence, I expect the code to compile successfully.

clang 4.0 compiles it successfully, whereas gcc 4.9.2 emits the following error:

```
 In constructor 'Grandchild::Grandchild()': 
16:27: error: use of deleted function 'Child::Child()' 
9:7: note: 'Child::Child()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed: 
9:7: error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()' 
9:7: note: candidates are: 3:5: note: Base::Base(int) 
3:5: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided 
1:7: note: constexpr Base::Base(const Base&) 
1:7: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided 
1:7: note: constexpr Base::Base(Base&&) 
1:7: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

What does the standard say about this?

Comment: Why are you using virtual inheritance in the first place?

Comment: @Ron I don't get it, is there something wrong with using virtual inheritance? Anyway, I am doing it because I want to initialize the base class member in the most derived class.

Comment: [gcc9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dhM0nJyRL1zKVQ3B) seems working fine.

Comment: I only get the error if I select C++11, with C++14 it compiles fine live: https://godbolt.org/z/nZdAln  Perhaps you need to tell your compiler to use C++14?

Comment: @RichardCritten Ok, so seems to be a gcc bug? It fails with version 4.9.2, but seems to have been fixed in the later versions. Anyway, I would be interested to read the relevant section from the standard on this, so that I can understand exactly what they "fixed". PS: I have compiled with C++14, hence also the tag on the question.

Comment: GCC language support page: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14

Comment: @RichardCritten I see that it fails with version 6.3.0 as well. Due to certain ... corporate reason, I cannot install a later version. Regardless, I guess the rule of base class constructor being called from the most derived class in case of virtual inheritance is from C++98?

Comment: That's pretty much how virtually-inherited classes have always worked. The most-derived class is responsible for constructing all virtual superclasses.

Comment: Certainly a gcc bug. There is this note in [class.base.init] that clarifies what should happen: *An abstract class ([class.abstract]) is never a most derived class, thus its constructors never initialize virtual base classes, therefore the corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted.* Which is the case of `Child`. If the virtual destructor of `Child` is removed, so all compiler reject the code with this same error.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66443

Answer (score 2):

It seems there was a change in the C++ standard clarifying the requirements of generated constructors for `virtual` base classes. See [CWG257](http://wg21.link/CWG257). As far as I understand this text your situation should be allowed. Prior to the change the situation was unclear.

This change was voted into the Working Paper in October 2009, i.e., it should be applicable to compiling with C++11.

Comment: Prior situation was that such constructors were clearly ill formed